# Installing gcc 4.7.2 in MacOS (Monterrey)

Tags: macos, gcc, macports, g++

I am trying to install gcc 4.7.2 (I need this version in order to be able to compile an old code), but I can not seem to find a proper way to do it. It looks like the only available options is to do it via [Macports](https://ports.macports.org/port/gcc47/details/). However, seems it hasn't be working for many OS X versions. Could anyone give me an idea, please?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

That version is a decade old. It's possible you're the first person that's ever needed to run that particular version on macOS Monterey. You might have to port it yourself, or you might decide it's easier to fix up your other old code to compile with modern tools.